# css url() not recognized in internet explorer 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have this line in my CSS:

```
.ui-icon-zoom-in { content: url(images/16x16/ZoomIn.png); }
```

Which I am using with [jQuery UI Button widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/) like this:

```
$("#zoomin").button({ text: false, icons: { primary: "ui-icom-zoom-in" } });
```

In Chrome, I can see the image centered within the button.  However, in IE10, I do not see the image.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you declared doctype? I know IE sometimes doesn't support CSS3 unless you declare HTML5 doctype on the first line:

`<!doctype html>`

In correct CSS, `content` tag is only valid on `before` and `after` pseudo elements. You may be better off just appending the image using jquery.

Comment: Yes.  I have <!DOCTYPE html> declared in _Layout.cshtml

Comment: As I say below, you can't use `content` on anything except `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Chrome should not be rendering it. (I know, gasp, for once IE is the one behaving correctly!)

Comment: You'd be surprised at how often IE is right since IE9. IMHO it's become a much better browser than Gecko over the past 2~3 years, and I've frequently seen it outperform Webkit in complex CSS3 implementations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `content` property is only valid on :before and :after pseudo-elements. You should change it to:

```
.ui-icon-zoom-in { 
  background: url(images/16x16/ZoomIn.png) no-repeat; 
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
}
```

Apart from that, IE8+ only supports `content` property if a valid DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: This is poor for accessibility, people using high contrast modes will not see images set as `background`.

Comment: @Oshawott I'm just answering the question, I do not contest that the valid solution should have an `img` element with proper `alt` attribute.

Comment: This is close to the answer I needed: .ui-icon-zoom-in {width: 16px;height: 16px; background-image: url(images/16x16/ZoomIn.png) !important; }

Comment: Why is it that https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator does not pick up on this issue? I ran a sheet through it that "naively" applies `content:` to a selector that is neither `:before` not `:after`, and it's all green.

Answer (score 2):

The `content` property is only accepted on `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in CSS3. You should probably use a jQuery selector to append the image to the object:

```
$("#zoomin").html("<img src='images/16x16/ZoomIn.png' alt='Zoom In'>");
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I do not want to hard code image locations in code.  I will like to stick to the pattern recommended by jQuery UI.

Comment: In that case, use a `:before` element absolute positioned at 0,0 with a `content` CSS tag. It's not semantically correct but should work. So like `.ui-icon-zoom-in:before { top: 0px; left: 0px; position:absolute; content: url(images/16x16/ZoomIn.png); }` then make `.ui-icon-zoon-in` a 0px wide, 0px high with `position:relative`.

Comment: Thanks again. What do you mean by "make .ui-icon-zoom-in 0px wide, 0px high with position:relative"?  I am new to this stuff, so code helps better.

Comment: I mean, set the css on that element to `position: relative; width: 0px; height: 0px;` -- basically just makes it a reference for its `before` element.

Comment: OK, so in site.css, I have:  .ui-icon-zoom-in:before { top:0; left:0; position:absolute; content: url(images/16x16/ZoomIn.png); }.  Then in Index.cshtml, I have modified the <button> element to look like this: <button style="position: relative; width: 0px; height: 0px" id="zoomIn" data-bind="click : zoomIn">zoom in</button>.  Now, the button after the aforementioned, has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation in IE 11.
The content is `<div class="image"> </div>`
So in Chrome it works like this

```
.image {
  content: url("image.jpg");
}
```

To make it Works in IE i have set the `content` option to `:after` element. Like

```
.image:after {
  content: url("image.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `box-sizing` property to keep the dimensions, addind the new image as background image and pushing "out" the existing (old) inline-image by `padding-left`:

```
.image{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(https://yourdomain/yoursite/yourasset.png) no-repeat;
  width: 20px; /* Width of new image */
  height: 25px; /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 20px; /* Equal to width of new image */
}
```

`box-sizing` has a good webbrowser-support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Adopted from: https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/