# Why is the icon shown in some browsers while other it is not

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z1mdvkgq/

HTML:

```
<div class="test" style="overflow: hidden; width: 650px; height: 350px; background: #CCC; position: relative;">
  <div class='control' tabindex='1'>
    <div class='btn'></div>
    <i class="icon-search ion-search" style="
    content: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png');
    width: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
      top: 8%;
        outline: none;"></i>
  </div>
  <i class='icon-close ion-ios-close-empty'>CLOSE</i>
</div>
```

How can I fix the "+" is shown in Chrome but not in IE.

[css url() not recognized in internet explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132460/css-url-not-recognized-in-internet-explorer-10) explains to use background instead of `content` but that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css url() not recognized in internet explorer 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132460/css-url-not-recognized-in-internet-explorer-10)

Comment: Background doesn't show up in Chrome. I tried that approach already

Comment: Then maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202306/ff-and-ie-dont-load-img-src-from-css, if you already did this research *mention it*.

Comment: @Si8 you are using `content` on a regular element, not a pseudo element. The answer linked as a potential duplicate explains that.

Comment: I tried `background` instead of content and did the whole thing as the article explains but nothing.

Comment: @Si8 that's because (1 It has no height (2 you need to set the `background-size` to `contain`

Comment: Got it... it's an oversight on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using content on a non-pseudo element you should use background-image instead.

I've updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/z1mdvkgq/3/)

But it would go like this:

```
.icon-search {
  background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/add-128.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px; /* make sure to include height as well */
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 8%;
  outline: none;      
}
```

Comment: @Si8 Glad to help you, if it did solve your issue, make sure to mark it as the answer for future reference ;).

Comment: Yes... Need to wait 1 more minute... not sure why I got a downvote :/

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct syntax.

The `content` property is applicable to the pseudeo-elements `::after`, `::before`, `:after`, and `:before`.

If you want it to be display it in all browsers, you must create a pseudo element in the `<style></style>` or inside a .css file. Alternatively, you could put a `<img/>` tag inside you `<i></i>` element.

---

[Reference @ w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)